# Jenkins npm/gulp proxy setup

Tags: node.js, jenkins, proxy, jenkins-plugins, gulp

My client project is build via gulp & I would like to configure ci with Jenkins. I have a batch file to execute

```
npm install
gulp build
```

1. I am behind a authenticating proxy, Jenkins do not pickup  proxy details even though I have setup

   npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
   npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

& even setup `HTTP_PROXY` env variable on my Jenkins.

2. I there a Jenkins plugin for gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause was that Jenkins was running as a different user. When I change the Logon details of the Jenkins process to a user where PROXY details are setup, everything works fine.